# Android : calling a user defined method causing application misbehave

Tags: java, android, onclick

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Level1 ob = new Level1();
        ob.checkAns();
        int id = v.getId();
        String typed = ans.getText().toString();

        String resourceName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);
        ans.setText(typed + resourceName);


//      String check =ans.getText().toString();
//
//      if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC")){
//          Toast.makeText(Level1.this, "correct" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//      }
//      else {
//          Toast.makeText(Level1.this, "NO" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//      }
//  }
```

The given code is my `onClick()` method.
The commented area is the part for which i am interested to make a method. like this :

```
public  void checkAns() {
        String check =ans.getText().toString();

        if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC")){
            Toast.makeText(Level1.this, "correct" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(Level1.this, "NO" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and i want to call this in my onClick method as shown in the `onClick()` method i.e :

```
`public void onClick(View v) {
        Level1 ob = new Level1();
        ob.checkAns();....
```

`Level1` is my class name .
My question is that when i call method `checkAns()` from `onClick()` and i click any button, my application stopped
and when i use the same code of `checkAns()` code in the `onClick()` and removing the call statement of `checkAns()` the application works fine.
Hopefully my problems is understandable.
please help.

UPDATE: my Level1 class.

```
    package com.example.letsguesssomething;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Level1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    ImageButton A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J;
    TextView ans;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level1);

        A = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.A);
        B = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.B);
        C = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.C);
        D = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.D);
        E = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.E);
        F = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.F);
        G = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.G);
        H = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.H);
        I = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.I);
        J = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.J);
        ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        A.setOnClickListener(this);
        B.setOnClickListener(this);
        C.setOnClickListener(this);
        D.setOnClickListener(this);
        E.setOnClickListener(this);
        F.setOnClickListener(this);
        G.setOnClickListener(this);
        H.setOnClickListener(this);
        I.setOnClickListener(this);
        J.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Level1 ob = new Level1();
        //ob.checkAns();
        int id = v.getId();
        String typed = ans.getText().toString();

        String resourceName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);
        ans.setText(typed + resourceName);


        String check =ans.getText().toString();

        if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC")){
            Toast.makeText(Level1.this, "correct" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(Level1.this, "NO" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }



    }
public  void checkAns() {
    String check =ans.getText().toString();

    if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC")){
        Toast.makeText(Level1.this, "correct" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(Level1.this, "NO" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For a right answer** you must provide a stacktrace of your question.
There might be a problem with ans variable used in ans.getText(). Did you check if it has a not-null value assigned?

By the way, is your Level1 class an extension of Activity class? Because you are using Level1.this as a context provided for Toast.
In this case, the problem might be with your way of initializing Level1 object. Its not common to instantiate Activities with constructor.

**EDIT:**

The point is that you should never create an Activity Object inside an activity class like you've done in `Leve1 ob = new Level1()`. You can replace the

```
Level1 ob = new Level1();
ob.checkAns();
```

with

```
checkAns();
```

and **move** the checkAns function to your activity class, not out of it.
since checkAns() is a method of you Level1 class, you can call it wherever you want in your non-static class functions, which ofcouse includes onClick method.

The code below should work fine.

```
public class Level1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    ImageButton A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J;
    TextView ans;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_level1);

        A = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.A);
        B = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.B);
        C = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.C);
        D = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.D);
        E = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.E);
        F = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.F);
        G = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.G);
        H = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.H);
        I = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.I);
        J = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.J);
        ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ans);
        A.setOnClickListener(this);
        B.setOnClickListener(this);
        C.setOnClickListener(this);
        D.setOnClickListener(this);
        E.setOnClickListener(this);
        F.setOnClickListener(this);
        G.setOnClickListener(this);
        H.setOnClickListener(this);
        I.setOnClickListener(this);
        J.setOnClickListener(this);

    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        String typed = ans.getText().toString();

        String resourceName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);
        ans.setText(typed + resourceName);

        checkAns();

    }



    public  void checkAns() {
        String check =ans.getText().toString();
        if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC")){
            Toast.makeText(Level1.this, "correct" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(Level1.this, "NO" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the code inside the method is all correct because it is working fine when directly used in onClick().

Comment: there is nothing to do with Toast.because if i am removing the Toast statement still same problem occur that means something is wrong with this method calling r something i didnt get.

Comment: I know there is nothing write with the Toast :) but I asked if your Level1 class extends Activity/Application class.

Comment: There might be something wrong with Level1 class. Can you provide the code of Level1 class? Mainly the parts that contain ans variable.

Comment: I think I misunderstood. There is a ob.checkAns() method in your first code snippet, which is also seen in your third code snippet. Is your first code correct?

Comment: my first code is my onClick() which is working fine when i uncomment the commented lines and remove the lines Level1 ob = new .....

Comment: please recheck my question i have updated that for you.

Comment: I get it now, btw putting the stackTrace of your error helps much more with understanding the problem. Can your Level1 class object use same instance of "ans"?

Comment: there is no visible error.application just stops when i click any button.

Comment: i make the solution easier for u .i just want my commented code in the uppermost code to be in a method checkAns(). and call that method in onClick()

Comment: @cuteprogrammer : check my updated code. That is working one. Hope this resolves your issue !!!!

Comment: @cuteprogrammer If any of the solution works, you need to mark the same as answer. Or else up vote the answers so that for others it will be helpful....

Answer (score 1):

Note1: 
 If you are using all the logic in our Level1 class, why initialising an object of same class and calling the method ??? You can directly call **checkAns()**

```
Level1 ob = new Level1();
ob.checkAns();
```

Note2: Have you initialised your edit text in onCreate() ?

```
EditText ans;
ans=(EditText)findViewById(....);
```

This will work:
activity_main.xml is as follows

```
<ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/van"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtView"
            android:text="ABC"
            />
```

Activity Code:

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener{
ImageButton btn;
    TextView txt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgBtn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView);
}
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()== R.id.imgBtn){
            check(v.getId());
        }
    }
    private void check(int id){
        String resourceName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);
        String typed = txt.getText().toString();
        txt.setText(id+resourceName);
        Toast.makeText(this,"test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: edit text is initialized in the class outside the method onClick()

Comment: the method is not static then how can i call this without object?

Comment: let me make the solution easier for u .i just want my commented code in the uppermost code to be in a method checkAns(). and call that method in onClick()

Comment: i seriously appreciate and say bundles of thanks but... i want a method that contains check code.